# update angular from version 12 to 13 - Migration build issues - Warnings in moment

Tags: angular, webpack, momentjs, angular-moment

I am getting below warnings when upgrade from Angular 12 to 13. Any idea about this issue?

[image]

**package.json**:

```
"moment": "2.24.0",
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^13.1.0",
```

**custom-webpack-config**:
// To use the lang en while build

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
 
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/)
  ]
};
```

**angular.json**:

```
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["moment", "moment-business"]
```

**Note**:
we are not getting warning if we choose the lang other than 'en'
Tried 'zh' lang

ex:     new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\]locale$/, /zh/)

**Solutions tried/Referred**:

1,

```
"compilerOptions": {"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
} in tsconfig.json
```

2, https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5758

Comment: Ignore the warning or drop monent.js

Comment: cant drop moment js and at the same time i want to know why the warnings occur

Comment: Issue has been fixed now